# Catch activated user control c#

Tags: c#, events, userform

I am working with `C#`. I was wondering how to catch an event when a user control is activated?

I have created a document manager with `DevExpress` using `windowUIview`.

On the start page, I have `tiles`.

When I click `tiles_1`, it loads `userform_1`, I want to go back to start page and click `tile_1`, and start `userform_1` again. But I dont know how to do that.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "activated". "Control" has .GotFocus .Click .VisibleChanged and .EnabledChanged events, all of which are some form of "activation".

Comment: Please provide more details question. We can not understand what you want to say?

Comment: Have a look at: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) The look up which events are supported by your control. The basic method is: You add a new Eventhandler to your event. (`Control.Click += new EventHandler(this.methodToHandleEvent`)

Comment: This question is far to vague at the moment. Please edit it and provide more information

Answer (score 2):

From the design view in on your form click the control you want to work with then choose the lightning bolt from the properties window, this has all the possible events you can catch by default, then you can point the event to whatever code behind you like or have it create a stub for your code by double clicking the event.

Good luck